# recorrer cada item de un listbox , Python

Tags: python, bucle-for, scraping, listbox

Buen dia, Estoy buscando la forma de poder recorrer cada item un `Listbox` y puedo usarlos dentro de un for.

Especifico a fondo, Un `Listbox` de 3 items, al comenzar el recorrido comenzara por el primer item y este item lo usare para hacer webscraping, Extraera 1 numero, Suponiendo que es `24`. este 24 lo usare para recorrer del 1 al 24 en un `for`, Este `for` hara 24 raspados a 24 paginas. Al terminar de raspar la pagina 24. El Listbox tiene que pasar al siguiente item para que se haga el mismo proceso hasta terminar todo los items.

Pero como sabría el recorrido que el raspado del primer ítem ha terminado?

Con esto puedo agregar fácilmente ítems.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *


def agrega():
   lsttioanime.insert(END,tioa.get().replace('\n',""))
   lstname.insert(END,name.get().replace('\n',""))
   lstmonos.insert(END,monos.get().replace('\n',""))
def k():
   a=(lsttioanime.get(0, END))
   b=(lstname.get(0, END))
   c=(lstmonos.get(0, END))
   for k in a:
      print(k)
   for l in b:
      print(l)
   for ñ in c:
      print(ñ)

ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")

lsttioanime = Listbox(ventana)
lsttioanime.place(x=100,y=320)


lstname = Listbox(ventana)
lstname.place(x=230,y=320)


lstmonos = Listbox(ventana)
lstmonos.place(x=360,y=320)

fullname5 = StringVar()


lbanime = Label(ventana,text="Tio Anime:")
lbanime.place(x=80,y=17)

lbanime = Label(ventana,text="Nombre Anime:")
lbanime.place(x=60,y=37)

lbanime = Label(ventana,text="MonosChinos:")
lbanime.place(x=65,y=60)

tioa=StringVar()
name=StringVar()
monos=StringVar()

txttioa=Entry(ventana,textvariable=tioa).place(x=150,y=20)  

txtn=Entry(ventana,textvariable=name).place(x=150,y=40)   

txtmon=Entry(ventana,textvariable=monos).place(x=150,y=60)   


boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Guarda pls",command=agrega, width="10", height="2", bg="#00CD63").place(x=300,y=20)
boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="Comienza pls",command=k, width="10", height="2", bg="#00CD63").place(x=400,y=20)
ventana.mainloop()
```

¿Pero como implementaría lo que busco lograr?, Muchas gracias.

Comment: Que has intentado?

Comment: @Gabitohh, Gracias por responder. Estoy aprendiendo y mi primera vez con `Listbox`, Aun no encuentro la forma de poder guardar el primer ítem en una variable, Pero ando investigando!

Comment: Si deseas obtener en una lista todos los elementos del Listbox: `items = lstmaterias.get(0, tk.END)`, para iterar sobre esa lista: `for i in items:`, si deseas obtener el primer elemento del listbox: `lstmaterias.get(0)`.

Comment: Si pudieras poner un ejemplo de entrada-salida de lo que deseas, podría ser muy útil. Sé que lo explicas en la pregunta, pero creo que no queda muy claro.

Comment: @Firefly Gracias por responder, Logre extraer todo los elementos del Listbox, y luego use un `for` para tener en lista. Pero no me funciona como lo esperaba. Se supone que el primer ítem que devuelve el `for` lo usare en un `for` que se encuentra en otra función para hacer scraping. Y al terminar el scraping, El primer `for` tendría que dar el segundo para repetir el proceso, Pero nunca lo hace, Solo me devuelve el primer elemento. Probe el codigo solo y si devuelve la lista entera, Pero no comprendo aun porque no me funciona. Actualizo mi codigo al actual que funciona con totalnormalidad.

Comment: Vi que ahora tienes 3 Listbox, ¿cómo quieres que funcione tu sistema? Agrego los valores de los tres Entry y al dar clic en guardar, cada uno se inserta en su respectivo Listbox, luego que hay que hacer (desde el punto de vista de usuario) no de programador.

Comment: Buscaba coger todo los elementos del `Listbox` y usarlo en un `for`, Y es lo hice y ya lo logre, extraje todo los elementos de los  `Listbox`, se crearon tres listas y los use en un `for` con `zip`, Todo un éxito!.